# Jenkins pipeline Regex pattern not matching

Tags: regex, git, jenkins

Currently have an unusual problem, I am running through a list of tags and testing against a regex pattern to see if it matches.

```
def tags = sh ( script: "git ls-remote --tags git@bitbucket.org:<PATH_TO_GIT_REPO>.git ", returnStdout: true)
def tag_line = tags.split("\n")
tag_line.each
{
    tag ->
    // println(tag)
    current_tag = tag.split()[1].split("/")[2].trim()
    println("Current Line: " + current_tag)

    def major = (current_tag =~ /v.+\.\d+\.\d*/)
    println(major)

}
```

If I use a regex online tester the match is returned. However no matter what I do the output to the console is as follow :

```
Current Line: v1.9.0^{}
[Pipeline] echo
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=v.+\.\d+\.\d* region=0,9 lastmatch=]
[Pipeline] echo
Current Line: v1.9.1
[Pipeline] echo
java.util.regex.Matcher[pattern=v.+\.\d+\.\d* region=0,6 lastmatch=]
```

Comment: What do you need to get in the end? `v1.9.1`?

Comment: Well if I'm honest was originally using a capture group to grab just the first section, but just simplified it to see it would match anything. In this case yes just match '''v1.9.1'''.

Comment: Then add `if (major) {
    println major.group()
  }`

Comment: Shouldn't lastmatch return something ? expected it to contain something, pretty new to using regex in Jenkins.

Comment: No, `(current_tag =~ /v.+\.\d+\.\d*/)` is a matcher that has not been run.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `lastmatch` property is empty because with the `def major = (current_tag =~ /v.+\.\d+\.\d*/)` line of code you only initialized the Matcher object but have not "run" it.

To obtain a match, you need to first run it, and you may do it, say, by using

```
if (major) {
  println major.group()
}
```

If you have a capturing group in your regex pattern, use the appropriate ID inside `group()`.